# Excel Countifs that count duplicate entries once

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a countifs formula that counts duplicate entries once. See below example data set. With "Vegetable" being cell A1.

In it I am trying to count KPIs impacted (column D) of potato (column A), that are not mashed (column B), with "1 (ASS)" occurring in Data 1 (column C). Column D has both blank cells and "N/A" which cannot be counted. Column C displays data from a multi-select list, and is comma separated.

I have entered the formula to count the total number of KPIs in cell H2 on my workbook (see image). Answer is 3. The formula I used was

=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$22,"Potato",$B$3:$B$22,"<>"&"Mashed",$C$3:$C$22,"*"&$F$3&"*",$D$3:$D$22,"<>"&"",$D$3:$D$22,"<>"&"N/A")

However I can't create anything that will allow me to count the number of unique KPIs impacted. By unique I mean count the first instance / count duplicate entries once. The answer should be 2 in H3 (again, see image).

In my data set I can create a new column if necessary, but if there is way to answer this using just a formula that is my preferred solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
Vegtable    Type    Data 1                                     KPIs
Potato      Peeled  1 (ASS) xxx,11 (ToW) xxx                   1 ABC
Potato      Boiled  1 (ASS) xxx                                1 ABC
Potato      Mashed  1 (ASS) xxx                                3 ABC
Potato      Boiled  1 (ASS) xxx                                N/A
Potato      Boiled  1 (ASS) xxx                                N/A
Potato      Boiled  1 (ASS) xxx 
Potato      Peeled  1 (ASS) xxx                                7 ABC
Potato      Peeled  2 (ASS) xxx,8 (SGA) xxx                    8 ABC
Potato      Peeled  2 (ASS) xxx                                9 ABC
Potato      Peeled  2 (ASS) xxx                                10 ABC
Potato      Peeled  8 (SGA) xxx 
Carrot      Peeled  8 (SGA) xxx 
Carrot      Peeled  8 (SGA) xxx                                1 ABC
Carrot      Peeled  8 (SGA) xxx                                2 ABC
Carrot      Boiled  8 (SGA) xxx                                3 ABC
Carrot      Boiled  8 (SGA) xxx 
Carrot      Boiled  1 (ASS) xxx,8 (SGA) xxx,11 (ToW) xxx    
Carrot      Boiled  11 (ToW) xxx                               4 ABC
Carrot      Boiled  11 (ToW) xxx                               5 ABC
Carrot      Boiled  1 (ASS) xxx,11 (ToW) xxx                   6 ABC
```

[image]

Comment: You need to create a user-defined function in VBA for this.  I don't think it can be done with standard functions, unless some new ones have been added after the initial Excel 2016 release.

Comment: Alternately, you may be able to use a pivot table on another sheet, which should be configured to have one row per value of the field in question.  Then you can use `COUNT` to count the rows on that sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Array formula (**Keep in mind to enter the formula using** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>!!)

```
=SUM(IF(($A$2:$A$21="Potato")*($B$2:$B$21<>"Mashed")*($C$2:$C$21="1 (ASS) xxx")*($D$2:$D$21<>"N/A")*($D$2:$D$21<>""),1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,"Potato",$B$2:$B$21,"<>"&"Mashed",$C$2:$C$21,"1 (ASS) xxx",$D$2:$D$21,"<>"&"",$D$2:$D$21,$D$2:$D$21),0))
```

formula with Wildcard search:

```
=SUM(IF(($A$2:$A$21="Potato")*($B$2:$B$21<>"Mashed")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*1 (ASS)*",$C$2:$C$21,1)))*($D$2:$D$21<>"N/A")*($D$2:$D$21<>""),1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,"Potato",$B$2:$B$21,"<>"&"Mashed",$C$2:$C$21,"*1 (ASS)*",$D$2:$D$21,"<>"&"",$D$2:$D$21,$D$2:$D$21),0))
```

formula with Wildcard search and search-text in Cell F2:

```
=SUM(IF(($A$2:$A$21="Potato")*($B$2:$B$21<>"Mashed")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$F$2&"*",$C$2:$C$21,1)))*($D$2:$D$21<>"N/A")*($D$2:$D$21<>""),1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,"Potato",$B$2:$B$21,"<>"&"Mashed",$C$2:$C$21,"*"&$F$2&"*",$D$2:$D$21,"<>"&"",$D$2:$D$21,$D$2:$D$21),0))
```

Comment: That’s very nearly it. The issue I have is with the sum if criteria ($C$2:$C$21="1 (ASS) xxx") 

This can’t be an equals. It needs to search column C for specific strings of text…. There could be multiple, comma separated, criteria in each cell. In my original formula I used this: 

$C$2:$C$21,"*"&1 (ASS)&"*"

Don’t know how to recreate this criteria in your formula…

Comment: Could you give me an example, of the strings you are looking for?